# Object animator works only till the middle, not the bottom of scroll

Tags: java, android, animation, autoscroll

Animation launches, but goes only till the particular spot somewhere in the middle of the scroll. What could cause such strange behavior? Please, help with some advice!

```
public void scrollAnimation() {
    // Scroll activity!
    final ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollViewID);
    mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", mScrollView.getBottom());
            anim.setDuration(3000);
            anim.start();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AnimatorSet animators = new AnimatorSet();
 int y = 8000; // pixels how far will go the scroll
final ScrollView mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScrollViewID);
final ObjectAnimator yTranslate = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mScrollView, "scrollY", y);
animators.setDuration(100000L); // speed of scroll (greater the value -- greater the speed)

animators.play(yTranslate);
animators.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 values i think. Like this

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(v, "scrollY", 
v.getChildAt(0).getHeight()
- v.getHeight());
```